# Multiple 'if' statements without an 'else'

Tags: c++, if-statement

The code I have to write is basically a mini bank. It asks for an initial amount, the type of action, and a second operator for that action.

I'm not allowed to use `else`, but am allowed to use `if` statements (I don't understand why), nor am I allowed to use a loop or an array.

This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int operand1;
int operand2;
float output;
char action;

int main()
{
   cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

   cout << "Enter the initial balance [1-1000]: " << endl;
   cin >> operand1;

   cout << "Enter an action (D, W, I or C):" << endl;
   cin >> action;

   cout << "Enter the second operand:" << endl;
   cin >> operand2;

   if ((action != 'D' && action != 'W' && action != 'I' && action != 'C') || (operand1 > 1000 || operand1 < 1) || 
       (action == 'I' && operand2 > 15 || operand2 < 1) || (action == 'C' && operand2 != 20 && operand2 != 10 && operand2 != 5) ||
       (operand2 > 1000 || operand2 < 1))
   {
       cout << "Input out of range" << endl;
       return 0;
   }

   if (action == 'D')
   {
      output = (operand1 + operand2);
      cout << "The new account balance is " << output << endl;
   }

   if (action == 'W')
   {
      output = (operand1 - operand2);
      if (output<0)
      {
          cout << "Input out of range" << endl;
          return 0;
      }
       cout << "The new account balance is " << output << endl;
   }

   if (action == 'I')
   {

       output = ((float)operand1 + (((float)operand2 / 100) * (float)operand1));
       cout << "The new account balance is " << output << endl;
   }

   if (action == 'C')
   {
       output = operand1 % operand2;
       cout << operand1 / operand2 << " bills dispensed plus " << output << endl;
   }

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

On certain instances, I get multiple errors instead of just one. For example:

```
Enter the initial balance [1-1000]: 1030

Enter an action (D, W, I or C): D

Enter the second operand: 40

Input out of range
```

However, it seems to just move on when it sees the error anyway, and I get this output:

```
Enter the initial balance [1-1000]:

1030

Input out of range

Enter an action (D, W, I or C):

D

Enter the second operand:

40

The new account balance is 1070.00
```

I can't seem to figure out how to have only one output, and for it to just display the error with no balance, without using an `else` statement.

Comment: Please read about how to use `switch-case`.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using `else`?  If it works with `else` then use `else`. or else ;)

Comment: Store your comparison in a `bool` variable, and then check both cases explictly with two separate if statements.

Comment: If you use `return` when you encounter an error it should never move forward. Otherwise you can use some sort of `bool there_was_an_error` and set it to true and check for that with an if, but that's basically what `else` does... so it's a little weird.

Comment: @NathanOliver its for an assignment and it clearly states don't use else which is dumb haha

Comment: @kiranBiradar im looking into that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use switch (action):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

After the cases it can have a default.

Also lots of conventions forbid else, but not forbid elseif - are you sure elseif is forbidden in your case?

But even if elseif is allowed - switch is better to read and is a more elegant solution.

Comment: yeah im sure "• You are NOT allowed to use an else statement. You can use multiple if statements, some with compound conditions."

Comment: i still have the error proct before second output not after though with the switch statment

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch by taking all the commands as different cases. This is what others have already said.

My contribution would be that you could put your first if statement i.e. the error case under the default case.

And before using switch statements, could you check if it is ever explicitly stated that you can't use 'else if' statements. If not, you should use that. It is not the same as an 'else' statement.

Answer (score 0):

`&&` has a higher precedence than `||`

```
if (
    (action != 'D' && action != 'W' && action != 'I' && action != 'C') ||
    (operand1 > 1000 || operand1 < 1) ||
//  (action == 'I' && operand2 > 15 || operand2 < 1) ||
    (action == 'I' && (operand2 > 15 || operand2 < 1)) ||
    (action == 'C' && operand2 != 20 && operand2 != 10 && operand2 != 5) ||
    (operand2 > 1000 || operand2 < 1))
{
    cout << "Input out of range" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To have more traceability, on what the code does, it would be worth the effort to do:

```
if (action != 'D' && action != 'W' && action != 'I' && action != 'C')
{
    cout << "Input out of range; action " << action << endl;
    return 0;
}
if (operand1 > 1000 || operand1 < 1)
{
    cout << "Input out of range; 1st operand: " << operand1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
...
```